# Exponential diophantine: $(a^r+1)(b^s+1)=c^t+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've been trying to solve this for a while to no avail.

Problem: Find all integers $a,b,c,r,s,t$ such that $(a^r+1)(b^s+1)=c^t+1$.

(In fact, the problem I was trying to solve had $a^r+1,b^s+1\in \mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all primes.)

Any hints are appreciated. (You can also post a solution if you want.)

Comment: Here's one: $(2^1+1)(2^1+1)=2^3+1$. Also, $(a^r+1)(0^s+1)=a^r+1$ is a solution for all $a,r$ and $s>0$, as well as $(1^r+1)(1^s+1)=3^1+1$ and $(1^r+1)(0^s+1)=1^t+1$. I don't think there are any other "trivial" solutions.

Comment: Restricting $a,b,c$ to primes may help, otherwise the question is subsumed into $(a+1)(b+1)=c$ (every solution to the original is a solution of this, and every solution of this is a solution of the original for $r=s=t=1$ and $c\mapsto c-1$), which is obviously solvable for every $a,b$.

Comment: There are a series of solutions with squares such as $(n^2+1)((n+1)^2+1)=(n^2+n+1)^2+1$ such as $(2^2+1)(3^3+1)=7^2+1$ and $(4^4+1)(3^3+1)=13^2+1$ etc. Only the first involve primes.

Comment: The question is very general, even with your restrictions that $a^r+1$ and $b^s+1$ are primes. For instance if t=1 any choice for the other variables is part of a solution. But to comment on the equation with the requirement that t>1 we have that $a^r$ and $b^c$ are even so that they contain the factors $2^r$ and $2^s$. More generally we have a=-1 (mod a+1) and similar for b. Sometimes a more general problem is more interesting than a particular version (and there is a post on that) but most often the more general formulation becomes uninspiring because of the many solutions.

Comment: I am not sure. Look at $2^4 +1=17$. Anyway if t=1 all choices   give valid solutions. We must assume something like r,s,t,>1 perhaps.

Comment: If $a^s+1$ is a prime implies that s=2 (which escapes me just now) then $(2^2+1)(3^3+1)=7^2+1$ is the only candidate so far. Let me also mention to you that the $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)$ is a series of numbers who can be represented two ways as a sum of two squares, such as the above examples $7^2+1 = 5^2+5^2$ or $13^3+1 = 7^2+11^2$, so these are fairly well-known series. Another similar series is for odd numbers a and b: $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)/2$ starting with 65 $(8^2+1$ and $7^2+4^2)$ for a=3 and b=5

Comment: I note that $a^s+1=(a+1)(f(a)$ for s=3,5,6,etc. and so cannot be primes except for r and s =2, since that are >1, as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

I have an attemp here based on information added in the comments:

The LHS is composed of two primes e and d, so that $ed=c^t+1$
Let us first consider that the exponents are all >1 and that $ (a^2+1) $ and $ (b^2+1) $ are both primes.
Let the lower prime be d (d=e implies that t is even).

We first prove that $c^t$ must be a square. 
If t is even then c^t can be written as a square.

If t is odd $c^t=(c+1) (c^{t-1}+(-1)^{t-2}c^{t-2}…..+1) $ and

2nd Edit:

We assume that the first factor is d=c+1 and therefore

$a^2+1$ = c+1 and $a^2=c$ and therefore $c^t=(a^2)^t=(a^t)^2$ so that $c^t+1= f^2+1$ with $f=a^t$

We therefore must assume that $ (a^2+1) (b^2+1)=f^2+1$ or

$ (ab)^2+a^2+b^2=f^2$

The factors on the LHV are primes so both a and b must contain factors of 2 and $a^2b^2$ must contain a factor of 16.

Now divide with factors of 2 until at least one term on the LHD is odd.

We therefore have $4(a_1)^2(b_1)^2+a_1^2+b_1^2=f_1^2$
But $a^2$ and $b^2$ must be of the type 4n+1 since 4n (or 0 (mod 4)) is ruled out by our assumptions (and 4n+2 and 4n+3 are ruled out for squares) and the first term must be 0 (mod 4) and therefore f^2 must be of type 4n+2  which is not possible for a square.

What remains - if we disregard the restrictions on exponents and variables - are the trivial solutions for a,b,c=0 etc as mentioned in the comments by Mario Carneiro.

Comment: You are right - there is something missing.

Comment: You are right - there is something missing in the best of cases, I may also be completely wrong. Let me also point out that the step was too complicated - if we insert (-1) instead of d-1 we get $(1-(-1)^{odd}+1(-1)^{even} -...+1)$. Assuming I am right, one also need to consider e=t (by considering $e^t+1< or = e^2)$.

Comment: A few hours later: It occurred to me that your particular example is not valid since e and d both must be of the type 4n+1 primes since $a^2=d-14 $ and $b^2=e-1$ . Perhaps that is enough?

Comment: correction: $a^2=d-1$

Comment: @Ark: I believe the much simpler observations does it $a^2+1$ = c+1 and $a^2=c$ and therefore $c^t=(a^2)^t=(a^t)^2$ so that $c^t+1= f^2+1$ with $f=a^t$

Comment: The easy thing is to prove that t cannot be odd>3. $c+1=d=a^2+1$ implies c=a2 which is a contradiction for odd t. We still have to prove a,b,c ,r,s,t,$>1 $ will not work for t even, that  is for the RHS $c^t+1 =c^{2n}+1$. My proof above is wrong. Can you help out here?